# RuneAudio - Adding WebRadio Sources, Jamendo, or Dirble

Tags: audio, streaming

I have RuneAudio running on a Pi3, and it runs beautifully.

I am, however, having an issue adding external source material to the Library.

I have tried repeatedly to get the Jamendo app/plug in to do something ... anything ... but it just displays in the queue while refusing to play anything, regardless of which musical genre I select. Is there a secret that I need to know to get this to work?

Similarly, I have yet to find a Dirble "station" that will stream. Either it does nothing at all, or it announces that I need to find an app that is compatible with their 3rd party stream (usually radionomy.com). Am I doing something wrong, or are these options (Jamendo/Dirble) not what they appear to be?

Finally, I have added dozens of mp3/AAC web radio streams to the Web Radio library and attempted to load them into the queue, and thus far I can get only three to actually be recognized by RuneAudio.  Is there documentation that explicitly outlines how to properly enter the URI for a stream?  I find numerous documents that speak to what is supported but none that say, "Here's exactly how to load an internet stream in Rune." The UI seems pretty intuitive, but given my overwhelming failure, I guess it is not as simple as it appears.